# How to center a picture inside a div?

Tags: html, css

How to center a picture horizontally inside a div? Right now the picture is on the left, though it should be centered. I tried a lot including positioning but nothing works.

See the code below.

Thank You.

```css
.p_pic-1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 float: left;
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.p_pic-2 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 float: left;
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.p_pic-3 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 float: left;
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.p_pic-4 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 float: left;
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.p-1 {
 float:left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
  
 background: #a1a1a1;
}
.p-2 {
 float: left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
  
 background: #a1a1a1;
}
.p-3{
 float:left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
 
 background: #a1a1a1;
}
.p-4 {
 float: left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
   
 background: #a1a1a1;
}

.p-pics {

 width: 940px;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 70px auto 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.p-name {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #333;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.p-description {
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 float:left;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.p_wrap {

   width: 100%;     
 text-align:center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="p-pics">
  <div class="p-container">
  <h2 class="pa_h2">Head Text</h2>
  <div class="p-1">
   <a class="p_pic-1" href="index.html"></a>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text.</p>
   </div>
        </div>
  <div class="p-2">
   <a class="p_pic-2" href="index.html"></a>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text, text text text.</p>
   </div>
        </div>
  <div class="p-3">
   <a class="p_pic-3" href="index.html"></a>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text, text text text. Some very-very long text. Just a text, yeah.
   </div>
    </div>
  <div class="p-4">
   <a class="p_pic-4" href="index.html"></a>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text, text text text.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Is that what you want:     background: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg) center center;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add wrapper class to that image and set width height and margin: 0 auto; for that wrapper then it will get centered alignment

```css
.p_pic-1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 float: left;
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.p_pic-2 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 float: left;
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.p_pic-3 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 float: left;
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
.p_pic-4 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 float: left;
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.p-1 {
 float:left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
  
 background: #a1a1a1;
}
.p-2 {
 float: left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
  
 background: #a1a1a1;
}
.p-3{
 float:left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
 
 background: #a1a1a1;
}
.p-4 {
 float: left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
   
 background: #a1a1a1;
}

.p-pics {

 width: 940px;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 70px auto 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.p-name {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #333;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.p-description {
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 float:left;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.p_wrap {

   width: 100%;     
 text-align:center;
  
}
.pic-wrap {
   width: 122px;
   height: 122px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="p-pics">
  <div class="p-container">
  <h2 class="pa_h2">Head Text</h2>
  <div class="p-1">
          <div class="pic-wrap">
   <a class="p_pic-1" href="index.html"></a>
          </div>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text.</p>
   </div>
        </div>
  <div class="p-2">
          <div class="pic-wrap">
   <a class="p_pic-2" href="index.html"></a>
          </div>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text, text text text.</p>
   </div>
        </div>
  <div class="p-3">
          <div class="pic-wrap">
   <a class="p_pic-3" href="index.html"></a>
          </div>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text, text text text. Some very-very long text. Just a text, yeah.
   </div>
    </div>
  <div class="p-4">
          <div class="pic-wrap">
   <a class="p_pic-4" href="index.html"></a>
          </div>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text, text text text.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

```
background-position: center top;
```

Where the first "center" is the horizontal align and the "top" is the vertical one. You can also use `px`. it will move the image the amount of px from left to right (horizontal) and top to buttom (vertical)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.p_pic-1 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.p_pic-2 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
      display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.p_pic-3 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
      display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.p_pic-4 {
    background-image: url(http://www.templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg);
 
    width: 122px;
    height: 122px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
      display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.p-1 {
 float:left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
  
 background: #a1a1a1;
}
.p-2 {
 float: left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
  
 background: #a1a1a1;
}
.p-3{
 float:left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
 
 background: #a1a1a1;
}
.p-4 {
 float: left;
 width:220px;
 height: 100%;
 margin-left: 20px;
   
 background: #a1a1a1;
}

.p-pics {

 width: 940px;
 text-align:center;
 margin: 70px auto 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.p-name {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #333;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.p-description {
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
 float:left;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.p_wrap {

   width: 100%;     
 text-align:center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="p-pics">
  <div class="p-container">
  <h2 class="pa_h2">Head Text</h2>
  <div class="p-1">
   <a class="p_pic-1" href="index.html"></a>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text.</p>
   </div>
        </div>
  <div class="p-2">
   <a class="p_pic-2" href="index.html"></a>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text, text text text.</p>
   </div>
        </div>
  <div class="p-3">
   <a class="p_pic-3" href="index.html"></a>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text, text text text. Some very-very long text. Just a text, yeah.
   </div>
    </div>
  <div class="p-4">
   <a class="p_pic-4" href="index.html"></a>
   <div class="p_wrap">
   <h4 class="p-name">Some Text</h4>
   <p class="p-description">This is just a description, just a text, some text, text text text.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Try this, it was working fine....https://jsfiddle.net/maheswaran/eo25p0od/

Answer (score 0):

you can give

```
background: url(templatemo.com/templates/templatemo_406_flex/images/member1.jpg) center center;
```

Or

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

in each class where the background image exits.But Remember to remove the

```
float:left;
```

you have given earlier.